# Ergodicity in "unphysical" parts of Hilbert space

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, ergodicity

We know from Quantum complexity theory,  that the vast majority of states in Hilbert space for physically relevant Hamiltonians cannot be accessed except in exponentially long time (see related questions [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/703435/is-the-hilbert-space-description-of-quantum-many-body-physics-misleading-and-unp), and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/400841/why-are-interacting-electron-systems-hard-to-solve)). Thus, for a solid with $\sim10^{23}$ constituents, most of Hilbert space is irrelevant.

One of the building blocks of statistical mechanics of quantum systems is to assume a Gibbs distribution and ergodicity of the eigenstates. One expects the quantum system a non-zero temperature to be in some Gibbs mixed state of all eigenstates weighted by the Gibbs factor.

However, following the aforementioned result of quantum complexity theory, I would assume that for a generic Hamiltonian that some eigenstates are physically inaccessible in polynomial time. **How does one account for those (presumably) inaccessible states in quantum statistical mechanics?** If they are unaccounted for, how should one understand those eigenstates and ergodicity in that context?

Comment: Nice question. I am not going to attempt an answer, but I will suggest that an operational version of this question might help to sharpen the seeming contradiction, something like: "Can one use a Gibbs state as a resource to efficiently prepare one of the inaccessible states in Hilbert space" ? My guess is that the answer is *no*, because the Gibbs weights turn out to be exponentially small. Of course, a full accounting of your question will also treat the limit to which one can actually approximate a Gibbs state in some fixed time.

Comment: @Rococo At the end of their paper Poulin PRL 106, 170501 (2011), they argue that Gibbs states cannot reach those physically inaccessible states because their argument works for imaginary time evolution as well. I find myself confused here, but perhaps I am misunderstanding things. https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.106.170501

Comment: Indeed, the exact quote is that "thermal and ground states of local hamiltonians are also efficiently parametrized by short circuits" (for any readers who are confused, I will note that this statement is only in the published version of the paper, not the arxiv version). My understanding of this statement is that the vast majority of the weight for any Gibbs state (for local Hamiltonians) is in accessible states, such that one can prepare a good approximation to them with only these states.

Comment: Another short discussion of this issue is given in sec. 3.4 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.2164.pdf . For more concrete statements, I think, one has at some point to pick a concrete model (e.g. a Heisenberg spin chain) and study its level statistics.

Comment: What bothers me about those discussions is that when someone computes anything against a partition function of a model Hamiltonian, there is no care given to whether unphysical states are included. I would guess you'd get all sorts of wrong answers for the heat capacity, entropy, etc. But clearly calculations still work whilst ignoring this issue...